# Calls value not incrementing as intended

Tags: python, recursion, quickselect

I am writing a program meant to find the average number of recursive calls it takes to run quickselect, and I have added a counter "calls" to keep track of the number of recursive calls. I have it incrementing every time quickselect is called again, but when I use a larger number for main the number of calls quickly goes into exponential territory. I would like for main to return the average number of calls, and I know the number I am getting is wrong but I cannot tell why. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import random

def main(trials,k):
    i = 0;
    hold = []
    calls = -1;
    while i < trials:
        generate(hold, 75)
        calls = calls + quickselect(hold, k, calls)
        i = i + 1
    print(calls/trials)


def generate(l,n):
    for i in range(n):
        r=random.randint(0,n)
        if r not in l:
            l.append(r)


def quickselect(l, k, calls) :
    #l is the list of the numbers
    #we are finding the kth largest element
    calls = calls + 1
    length = len(l)
    pivotselect = numpy.random.randint(0,length,1)

    l = numpy.array(l)
 
    #print(pivotselect)
    #print(l[pivotselect])
    pivot = l[pivotselect]
    #print("this is the pivot", pivot)
    
    # Pick a random pivot element from the list, each
    # equally likely
    l_small = []
    l_big = []

    smalltrack = 0
    bigtrack = 0
    i = 0
    ispivot = 0
    while i < length:
        #print(i)
        compare = l[i]
        if compare < pivot:
            l_small.append(compare)
            smalltrack = smalltrack + 1
            #print(l_small)
        elif l[i] > pivot:
            l_big.append(compare)
            bigtrack = bigtrack + 1
        else:
            ispivot = ispivot + 1
            #print(compare, "ispivot is now", ispivot)
        i = i + 1
    #print("ispivot is", ispivot)
    #print(len(l_small), "small then big", len(l_big))
    checker = len(l_small) + len(l_big)
    #print(checker)
    checker = checker + ispivot
    #print(checker)
    assert(length == checker)
    l_big = numpy.array(l_big)
    l_small = numpy.array(l_small)
    #print("check 1")


    if k <= len(l_big):
        
    # kth largest must be in l_big
    
        res = quickselect(l_big, k, calls)
        #print("check 2")
        #calls = calls + 1
        return res
    elif k > len(l_big) + 1:
        
    # kth largest must be in l_small
    
        res = quickselect(l_small, k - len(l_big) - 1, calls)
        #print("check 3")
        #calls = calls + 1
        return res
    else:
        #print("check 4")
        #print("calls", calls)
        print(calls)
        return calls
```

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `l = numpy.array(l)`??

Comment: It was the only way I found to successfully resolve the typeError only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Because you are using `numpy.random`... why use `numpy` here *at all*, it doesn't make any sense. Just use the `random` module

Answer (score 0):

As your code is written, you are more than doubling `calls` each time you call `quickselect`.  You're passing it the current value, incrementing it by however many times `quickselect` is called, and then adding that new value of `calls` to your old value.

You need to get rid of either one addition or the other.  You can either:

- Call `quickselect` in `main` with the calls argument being 0. Continue to add the return result to `calls`.
- You can just call `quickselect(hold, k, calls)` and **not** add the return value to `calls`.